# printing whole binary tree on screen

Tags: c++, tree

I want to store numbers in a binary tree, exit with 0, then output the numbers in ascending order. Most answers I've seen were on searching in the tree, and the few that were covering this exact topic used methods that I didn't understand. I believe the tree itself is created correctly, but the output function is at fault. Where did I go wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

struct thing {
    short num;
    short howmany = 0;
    thing* right;
    thing* left;
};

void insert(thing* akt, short x) {
    if (akt == NULL) {
        akt = new thing;
        akt->left = NULL;
        akt->right = NULL;
        akt->num = x;
        akt->howmany++;
    }
    else if (akt->num == x) akt->howmany++;
    else if (akt->num > x) return insert(akt->right, x);
    else return insert(akt->left, x);
}

void output(thing* root) {
    thing* akt;
    do {
        akt = root;
        while(akt->left!=NULL) akt=akt->left;
        if(akt->right!=NULL) return output(akt->right);
        cout << akt->num << " " << akt->howmany << "times\n";
        akt = NULL;
    } while (root != NULL);
}

int main() {
    thing* root = new thing;
    short x;
    cout << "number: ";
    cin >> x;
    do {
        insert(root, x);
        cout << "number: ";
        cin >> x;
    } while (x != 0);
    cout << endl;
    output(root);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! To help us find the issue, please include *what output you are execting* (and why), and *what output you actually get* in your question (and try to create a [mcve]).

Comment: Check Boost Graph Library,it can print entire tree.

Comment: Your supposition of doing the insert correctly is wrong. Start with that. `akt = ...` means *nothing* to the *caller* of that function, *including itself*. Thankfully, at least that can be addressed easily in C++ by passing `akt` as a *reference* to a pointer, `thing *& akt`; not a pointer value as you're doing it now. Related, I cannot believe that function doesn't puke warnings, for several reasons, least of which is the `return` values specified for a `void` declared declared function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were multiple mistakes. First insert function was passing pointer by value so root was never modified.

Also corrected output function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

struct thing {
    short num;
    short howmany = 0;
    thing* right;
    thing* left;
};

void insert(thing* &akt, short x) {
    if (akt == NULL) {
        akt = new thing;
        akt->left = NULL;
        akt->right = NULL;
        akt->num = x;
        akt->howmany++;
    }
    else if (akt->num == x) akt->howmany++;
    else if (akt->num > x) return insert(akt->left, x);
    else return insert(akt->right, x);
}

void output(thing* root) {
    thing* akt = root;
    if(akt == NULL)
        return;

    output(akt->left);
    cout << akt->num << " " << akt->howmany << " times\n";
    output(akt->right);
}

int main() {
    thing* root = NULL;
    short x;
    cout << "number: ";
    cin >> x;
    do {
        insert(root, x);
        cout << "number: ";
        cin >> x;
    } while (x != 0);
    cout << endl;
    output(root);
    return 0;
}`
```

Comment: wow i screwed up badly. thank you for the corrected code, now i understand everything, it helped a lot!